# Is there an easy way to unpack two arrays/varargs in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Lets take a look at this pseudo code example:

```lua
-- Wraps a function with given parameters inside a callback
-- Usefull for sending class methods as callbacks.
-- E.g. callback(object.method, object)
local function callback(func, ...)
    return function(...)
         func(..., ...)
    end
end
```

How would I go about this?
I know there is unpack, but it would get swallowed by the second vararg:

```lua
local function callback(func, ...)
    local args = { ... }
    return function(...)
         func(table.unpack(args), ...)
    end
end

callback(print, "First", "Second")("Third") --> prints First Third
```

The only option I found so far, is to concat those together and then unpack it:

```lua
local function callback(func, ...)
    local args1 = { ... }
    return function(...)
         local args2 = { ... }
         local args = { }
         for _, value in ipairs(args1) do
               table.insert(args, value)
         end

         for _, value in ipairs(args2) do
               table.insert(args, value)
         end

         func(table.unpack(args))
    end
end
```

Is this the only solution, or could I do better?
What I would like to have is either a function, that concats two arrays together (which should be faster than those two for loops) and then use `table.unpack` on it, or make those varargs concat.

Comment: There is a mistake in your last example. remove `...` from `func(table.unpack(args), ...)` . `...` is already in `args` and the list returned by `table.unpack(args)` will be adjusted to 1 expression as it is not the last expression in a list of expressions.

Comment: Oh you are right, I missed to remove the ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.4 Expressions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4)

> If an expression is used as the last (or the only) element of a list
> of expressions, then no adjustment is made (unless the expression is
> enclosed in parentheses). In all other contexts, Lua adjusts the
> result list to one element, either discarding all values except the
> first one or adding a single nil if there are no values.

So the only way is to manually combine both lists to a single one befor you use them.

There are several ways to do this.

```
for i,v in ipairs(list2) do
  table.insert(list1, v)
end

for i,v in ipairs(list2) do
  list1[#list1+i] = v
end

table.move(list2, 1, #list2, #list1 + 1, list1)
```

I'm not sure what kind of problem you're actually trying to solve here.
If you want to access your object from its methods use self.

> -- Wraps a function with given parameters inside a callback
> -- Usefull for sending class methods as callbacks.
> -- E.g. callback(object.method, object)

Usually you would do something like this:

```
local callback = function(params) object:method(params) end
callback(params)
```

Instead of

```
callback(print, "First", "Second")("Third")
```

You could do this

```
local callback = function (...) print("First", "Second", ...) end
callback("Third")
```

#### Edit ( opinonated )

> My main goal is to use member functions as callbacks. However, I'd
> like to keep it general. The advantage of a callback function is to
> omit the function and end keyword. It's shorter and looks closer to
> what it would look like, if there would be no need for a self
> argument. So this: object.event = function(...) return
> self:method(...) end would become to this: object.event =
> callback(self.method, self) what would be even nicer, is this (sadly
> not possible in lua) object.event = self:method

So instead of

```
RegisterCallback(function() obj:method() end)
```

You say it is easier to do this, so you don't have to write `function` `end`?

```
local function callback(func, ...)
    local args1 = { ... }
    return function(...)
         local args2 = { ... }
         local args = { }
         for _, value in ipairs(args1) do
               table.insert(args, value)
         end

         for _, value in ipairs(args2) do
               table.insert(args, value)
         end

         func(table.unpack(args))
    end
end

RegisterCallback(callback(obj.method, obj)())
```

Your approach is not going to work if any of the arguments is nil to begin with. And there is not a single advantage. You're just typing other words while increasing the chance of running into errors.

Comment: My main goal is to use member functions as callbacks. However, I'd like to keep it general. The advantage of a callback function is to omit the function and end keyword. It's shorter and looks closer to what it would look like, if there would be no need for a self argument. So this: `object.event = function(...) return self:method(...) end` would become to this: `object.event = callback(self.method, self)` what would be even nicer, is this (sadly not possible in lua) `object.event = self:method `

Comment: Sadly not possible if not using Luas strongest feature: metatables  metamethods -  Making a table act as function? - No problem with metamethod __call - Using functions on table with table as argument? - Just fill up the table __index with functions exactly matching the things you wanna do with that table .

Answer (score -1):

You can control the param order to optimize your function.

```
local function callback(func, ...)
    local args = {...}
    return function(...)
        func(..., table.unpack(args))
    end
end

callback(print, "second", "third")("first") -- prints first second third
```

Comment: It's not really what I asked for. Also this would not work with your solution:
`callback(print, "third")("first", "second") --> prints first third, instead of first second third`
Its because `func(..., table.unpack(args))` only selects the first argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `...` or `table.unpack` only select the first argument when they are not the last param.